# BASH Tools for conf file manipulation?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am wondering if there are any tools for use in bash scripts that can easily allow you to ***manipulate*** (**add, remove, update**) directives inside conf files?

e.g.
fail2ban.conf has grouped directives, each under their own sections.

```
[proftpd]
enabled  = true
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data

[postfix]
enabled  = true
port     = smtp,465,submission
```

whereas pagespeed.conf has mixed directives, some in their own sections and some arrayed all over.

```
<Location /pagespeed_admin>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from localhost
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        SetHandler pagespeed_admin
    </Location>
    <Location /pagespeed_global_admin>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from localhost
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        SetHandler pagespeed_global_admin
    </Location>

    ModPagespeedMessageBufferSize 100000
    ModPagespeedStatisticsLogging on
    ModPagespeedEnableCachePurge on
    ModPagespeedPurgeMethod PURGE
    ModPagespeedFileCacheSizeKb 2048000
    ModPagespeedFileCacheCleanIntervalMs 3600000
    ModPagespeedFileCacheInodeLimit 500000
```

You get the idea.

Are there any tools that allow you to :
e.g.
manipulate the 'enabled' directive in the 'proftpd' section of fail2ban.conf?

or
manipulate the 'Allow from' directive in the 'Location /pagespeed_admin' section of pagespeed.conf?

or
manipulate the 'ModPagespeedMessageBufferSize' directive in the 'no particular' section of pagespeed.conf?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is way too broad. And probably you don't want to manipulate config files from bash. Check automated solutions for it like ansible, salt, etc. These tools allow much more flexibility, allow you to manage multiple servers at a time and you can move almost anything to variable to rule your configuration.

Comment: I disagree. The question is quite to the point. If there is nothing out there in the form of a simple script or command that you are aware of, then fine. But to suggest that we need a paid solution to modify conf files is overkill. Thanks for the suggestion but this is not what I asked for.

Comment: ansible and salt are not a paid solution. They are open source industry wide used  configuration management tools.

Comment: anything in the script/command category? something simple?

Comment: git-config and postconf are the 2 tools I know of. Normally I use regex; perl -pi -e 's///g' file

Comment: Maybe jq and yq for JASON and XML

Comment: git-config looks like something that may be worth looking into further. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the way people usually do it is by using a unified conf dir with files in a simple format, and generate from it temporary conf files in the idiosincratic format expected by each app, which could be easily done even in shell. Look at OpenWRT with its [UCI](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/uci). A configuration tool able to modify all kind of configuration files (xml, ini, etc) will be more complicated and brittle than everything ever written.

Answer (score 1):

No, for the simple reason that there are just too many formats a configuration file might use. The best you can do, I think, is to roll your own using text-processing tools.

There may be libraries for some formats (JSON, for example) but tool authors are free to use whatever format they feel like so a general tool will not be possible. Just to illustrate the point, here are a few lines from a few conf files:

1. emacs

   ```
   ;; Are we running XEmacs or Emacs?
   (defvar running-xemacs (string-match "XEmacs\\|Lucid" emacs-version))

   ;; disable menu bar when running in terminal
   (when (not (display-graphic-p))
     (menu-bar-mode -1))

   ;;My libraries, ebib, wordcount etc
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs-lisp/")
   ```
2. vi

   ```
     highlight Normal guibg=grey90
     highlight Cursor guibg=Green guifg=NONE
     highlight lCursor guibg=Cyan guifg=NONE
     highlight NonText guibg=grey80
     highlight Constant gui=NONE guibg=grey95
     highlight Special gui=NONE guibg=grey95
   ```
3. tint

   ```
   #---------------------------------------------
   # BACKGROUND AND BORDER
   #---------------------------------------------
   # general panel settings
   rounded = 7
   border_width = 2
   #background_color = #B4B2B2 10
   background_color = #000000 30 
   border_color = #8F0004 0
   ```
4. vlc

   ```
   # Trigger button (string)
   #gestures-button=left

   [motion] # motion control interface

   [oldrc] # Remote control interface

   # Show stream position (boolean)
   rc-show-pos=0
   ```
5. sshd

   ```
   AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
   ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
   UsePAM yes
   ```

etc., etc.

Comment: again I disagree. what you posted above is just a simple scenario of key-value pairs. Nothing complicated to accomplish. Look for key.... paste value. done.

Comment: Maybe my question is being misinterpreted. 
I am not asking for an all knowing tool. I am asking for a tool which can take these key value pairs and it will go in the conf and replace them.

Comment: @conanDrum what conf? What format? You show two very different formats in your question. I am just trying to illustrate that there is no one standard format, so what you're asking for is not very clear. Conf files can use completely arbitrary formats devised by their tool's author.

Comment: thanks, and I am trying to say that we don't care about format if the user of the tool is aware of it and provides it as input to the tool. I am guessing noone thought of that before.

Comment: @conanDrum you are assuming that is possible, but it isn't. Not unless the tool is using some sort of standard format like `pagespeed.conf` which is using XML. However, many conf files will have arbitrary formats, so you would have no way of providing the format as input. There are tools that let you manipulate XML, that's something.

Comment: well, I have an idea in mind and almost implemented. very simple stuff but it works on both the above examples, and I am sure will work in many more.

Comment: @conanDrum yes, it will work on those that happen to use one of those two formats. And yes, both of those formats are indeed used by many programs. So if you have something, then great.

Comment: @conanDrum "I am not asking for an all knowing tool" is something it's probably worth adding to your question (editing it). I guess many readers might think that that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but you could build something for a specific config layout. Something like

`sed -E "/\[proftpd]/,/\[/{s/(enabled\s*=\s*).*/\1false/}" input.file`

could be designed as a function to change fail2ban.conf, as an example.

I could expand if at all interesting.

Comment: doing this already thank you for commenting